# Content in two rows, and any number of columns

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

**Update:** Found a solution. May need some fine-tuning but it works. For folks who may be looking for something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/wvqg8ceg/

**Original post:**
I'm trying to put together a 2-row layout that would place itself into columns. Like this:

```
1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
2 | 4 | 6 | etc.
```

Can be DIVs or LIs, that doesn't matter. But it's vital that the items get placed below each other, not just in a row like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
5 | 6 | 7 |
```

Also, it should work with any number of columns, and that's where I'm stuck. If it helps, the items are WordPress posts which I can wrap in UL or DIVs. But if I'd get it to work in simple HTML like shown below, I could carry that over. Suggestions?

Got a Fiddle here to work off of: http://jsfiddle.net/4jyok9ey/

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Maybe it's best to let them insert a table.

Comment: Are you talking about tables through css or an actual <table>?

Comment: Depends on the situation, but there are many good cases for actual tables. Of course, your question shows just a list of numbers, so there is no way to tell if it would be good in this case...

Comment: I used number here for simplicity's sake. They represent the content which I can format accordingly afterwards. The main thing would be getting this simplified HTML working.

Comment: Made a little progress. Got it almost where it needs to be but sadly on FF only: http://jsfiddle.net/4jyok9ey/3/

Comment: And this works on Chrome only :) http://jsfiddle.net/4jyok9ey/5/

Comment: Improved version with column break disabled on the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/4jyok9ey/7/ But that also works only in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. May need some fine-tuning but it works. For folks who may be looking for something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/wvqg8ceg/

```
ul {
    width:100px;
    height:220px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

    -webkit-column-width:100px;
    -moz-column-width:100px;
    column-width:100px;

}
ul li {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:5px 5px 10px 0;
    border:2px solid #999;
    text-align:center;
}
ul li:first-child,
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something simple ?

```
<div style="width:20%;float:left;"><ul> <li> 1 </li> <li> 2 </li> </div>
<div style="width:20%;float:left;"><ul> <li> 3 </li> <li> 4 </li> </div>
<div style="width:20%;float:left;"><ul> <li> 5 </li> <li> 6 </li> </div>
<div style="width:20%;float:left;"><ul> <li> 7 </li> <li> 8 </li> </div>
```

Comment: Don't think that'll do as the number of items are created by the user on-the-go. Should've probably mentioned that in the original post. So all the LIs would have to be inside a single UL, or alternatively they'll all just be DIVs.

Comment: How are users adding items? Please add this information to the question, since it is still relevant to get good answers.

Comment: It's WordPress posts.